# When does it make sence to use a resolve to retrive Data

Tags: angular

I am wondering if and when it makes sense to use a resolver vs just using a basic get data when page is opened. I have an app where multiple developers worked on and one of them used code in routes to lookup data before we opened the actual form like this.

```
{
    path: 'FarmMaster/:DocId',
    component: FarmMasterWrapperComponent,
    resolve: {'farmMaster': FarmMasterResolver},
    data: {displayName: 'Farm Master'},
}
```

i could do the same on ngInit to call the same service and get the data. As i want to standardize i would like to see which makes more sense and then go with that solution. There is always more then one way to do it and just because it works its not always the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Using a resolver gives you some more options:

- you can actually let the resolver act like a guard and prevent the user from entering the route
- if you have child routes you can reuse the result of the resolver of the parent route, which leeds to less calls, if you need the same data inside the child routes

and maybe some more I was not thinking of right now.

I want to give you some more hints on when I would prefer using a resolver vs. calling data inside the component.

- Very obvious: When I can make benefits of one of the mentioned options above, I would definitely use a resolver
- When the called data is used to get displayed in the component (for example a list of users) I would prefer loading it inside the component, since you very likely need a reload for example after adding a new entry or for filtering. So I would need the logic of loading inside the component anyway